How do sklearn's trees evaluate NaNs on inference?
Imagine we have fitted a sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier object like this one:

If we wanted to predict the class of this observation:
x = {
    "col_58": 5000,
    "col_1110": 0,
    "col_28": None,
    ...
}

I thought it would fall on node #6 because I have seen the object DecisionTreeClassifier create splits of the kind col_1 <= inf, and I assumed "inf" meant NaN. But when I tested this tree, I am getting node #3 when I do my_fitted_tree.apply(x).
Should this example of observation fall in node #3 or node #6? And why?

sklearn's documentation spells out how missing data are handled by tree:

By default when predicting, the samples with missing values are classified with the class used in the split found during training.

If the criterion evaluation is the same for both nodes, then the tie for missing value at predict time is broken by going to the right node. The splitter also checks the split where all the missing values go to one child and non-missing values go to the other.

If no missing values are seen during training for a given feature, then during prediction missing values are mapped to the child with the most samples.


The document contains code examples which makes it easy to see how these rules apply.

This is helpful, but I don't think it actually answers the question?

@BenReiniger OP's cases probably falls under criteria #3, where decision tree chose the node with more samples (3.7% > 3.0%). But can be #1 too.

This isn't really possible to answer without seeing your dataset, so you'll need to look more into it yourself.
My guess is that it's probably imputing the mean. Look into what the mean value is for col_28, and if it's less than 1.5, then that's likely why that sample is landing on node 3.
If you'd like to confirm this and you're comfortable working in the terminal, I'd recommend using the python debugger (pdb), setting a breakpoint before you call model.predict, and then step into/through the predict function.
Hope this helps!
